# iOS Push Notification Error: {reason: 'TopicDisallowed'}

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, push, node-apn

[Please read carefully before answering.]

I'm struggling to resolve notifications for more than a week and still, it's halfway resolved.

- I'm using the production certificate.
- It's working fine sometimes and suddenly starts throwing: { reason: 'TopicDisallowed' }
- It's working perfectly fine on localhost.
- It works fine sometimes on the server too (the issue is unstable). It automatically starts working and stops.

Here is the provider config:

```
const apn = require('apn'); // version: "apn": "^2.2.0"
const iosOptions = {
  token: {
    key: path.resolve('./lib/AuthK*********.p8'),
    keyId: '*********',
    teamId: '*******'
  },
  production: true
};

const apnProvider = new apn.Provider(iosOptions);
```

```
const apnNotification = new apn.Notification();
apnNotification.sound = 'default';
apnNotification.title = 'Hello';
apnNotification.body = 'Hello message';
apnNotification.aps.threadId = 'thread_id';
apnNotification.topic = topic;
apnNotification.payload = payload;

return apnProvider.send(apnNotification, token)
```

Is there anything wrong with the config?

`Error message: reason: 'TopicDisallowed'`

Please help if someone knows the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've resolved it by removing the package and writing a custom notification sender with Apple's official documentation for https://api.push.apple.com.

Here's more: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW3